# Creating COM serial port between external device (ie Intel Joule or Arduino, etc.) and PC over Bluetooth w/ linux sdptool & rfcomm (OR another method)

Tags: linux, bluetooth, arduino, serial-port

**I have moved most the support question to IoT as it pertains more to that site. If you have any questions or comments or answers, please direct them to this site:**
https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/creating-com-serial-port-between-external-device-ie-intel-joule-or-arduino-etc

**This question is no longer Joule device specific. More information can be found at the link, below is a summarized version. This question may be removed shortly from StackOverflow!**

I am currently trying to create a COM port connection between my PC and the Intel Joule platform. I have been able to do it with a cord but I would like to control it over Bluetooth. I've already paired the device with my computer and am currently following this tutorial:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/721513

I am able to add a serial port with:

```
sdptool add SP
```

But when I run rfcomm to watch to port using:

```
rfcomm watch hci0 1 getty rfcomm0 115200 vt100 -a root
```

I receive this:

```
RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
RFCOMM socket layer initialized
RFCOMM ver 1.11
Waiting for connection on channel 1
```

From there I return to my PC's Bluetooth settings and traverse to COM Ports (none show up). SO I click Add... and I've tried both Incoming and Outgoing connection (choosing the paired joule device). The result is this error:

> The device you selected does not have a serial port service running

... but I mean in the device it's saying "waiting for connection on channel 1"

Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Not a direct answer, but a related warning: Intel just announced the discontinuation of the Joule, Galileo, and Edison product lines. http://hackaday.com/2017/06/19/intel-discontinues-joule-galileo-and-edison-product-lines/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: haha what jww!? This is programming in Linux, and it's also used in development. There are many similar questions on this site! I see on the side alone: Bluetooth serial device detect COM, how can I create a serial connection between my phone and an Arduino, Arduino com port doesn't work. I've seen and used stack overflow for countless problems like this for programs like Unity and CAD where the questions have no scripting! Also to achieve this COM connection I need to program! I'm sorry sir but I think this question is perfectly fine here. Sorry If I'm coming off rude, I'm nice I swear! :P

Comment: That being said, I'll probably mosey on over to those other sites for extra support, I appreciate that mate!

Comment: @jww I moved the question to IoT,  if you would like to close this question you may. For now I'll just have it link to the IoT help page.

Comment: @SamH. Saw your question on arduino stackexchange site. It might be coming very late but have you considered using ROS for this? Through ROS you can have a serial bridge over bluetooth. This allow devices to communicate similar to that of serial (COM) connection.